# How to make PuTTy window a certain size from command line?

Tags: putty

I using PuTTy to SSH to a server, but I need the terminal window that opens to be small, only a certain x by x size, is there a ways to do this from command line?

Answer (score 6):

[PuTTY Standard command line parameters](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3) does not mention any options for specifying a window size or a font size.

However, you can specify a profile to load, and that can be used to accomplish what you're seeking.
A profile is basically a collection of settings, including window properties, remote server name, authentication keys, and more.  Some of those settings, like the server name, can be left blank if desired.

Make a profile using the GUI.  To change the window size, go to the screen of Window options.  (That is *above* the "Appearance" screen.  The word "Window" is a category that is above other screens in the hierarchy.  But, it is also a screen of options.)  Then, after specifying the size you want, go to the "Session" screen and type in a session name, and click "Save".  That creates the profile.

Then, use:

> PuTTY -load "sessionName"

Customize the part after the -load and between the quotes.  Specify the full path to PuTTY as required.

Some more official documentation for you: [PuTTY: Specifying a session to start with](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-startsess).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PuTTY supports this on the command line.  You can however, setup a profile with the "Columns" & "Rows" properties set on the "Window" settings pane.  You can then load the profile using:

```
putty -load "Profile Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

As other menchion, you need to load a profile to do so.
If you still want to automatically log in, put the username+password after the -load parameter like this (this is how my windows desktop shortcut looks):

> C:\apps\putty.exe -ssh -P 2222 -load "PROFILE NAME" USERNAME@192.168.0.10 -pw PASSWORD

If -load is the last parameter, passing username and password does not work.
The -P is only for servers not running default port 22.